# OBJ Texture Export doesn't work with Diffuse Shader?

Tags: shaders, export, obj

I got a model which I should export as OBJ with Material Infos + Textures so it could be used in Unity easily. I adjusted my Settings (Checked Materials + Paths Copy) and exported my objs and saw that some had a referenced texture in the mtl file and some had not.

So I tested and noticed that the Materials that used Mixed Shaders or the Diffuse Shader didn't reference the texture, while when I replaced the Diffuse with the Pricipled BSDF it now does everything fine.

Is there an explanation for that? Or a workaround? Otherwise I'd be not able to use more complex shaders for export.

Comment: Read through https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures